# Getting Bad request error while creating azure automation account runbook through terraform code

Tags: azure, automation, terraform, azure-runbook

I am creating a simple runbook through the terraform code. Below is the code that I am using:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_runbook" "example" {
  name                    = "AzureVMslist"
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.example.name
  log_verbose             = "true"
  log_progress            = "true"
  description             = "This is an example runbook"
  runbook_type            = "PowerShell"
  publish_content_link {
    uri = "" #not mentioning my uri
  }
}
```

terraform plan is successful and when I ran terraform apply then getting below:

> azurerm_automation_runbook.example: Creating...
>
> Error: creating/updating Runbook: (Name "AzureVMslist" / Automation Account Name "automation123" / Resource Group "poc_terraform"): automation.RunbookClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="{"Message":"Invalid argument specified. Argument content cannot be null."}"

How can we fix this error?

Comment: So the `uri` exists you only omitted it from the question?

Comment: Hi Marko, yes and the rest of the code is same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and I have fixed it. The issue is because of the dummy/empty uri that we are using for publish_content_link. So we need to use the Valid uri so that the runbook will get create automatically.

I have fixed this issue by taking one sample powershell script file and I have used that file in the code.

```
data "local_file" "example" {
  filename = "${path.module}/AzureVM.ps1"
}
```

and we have use the content = data.local_file.example.content instead of publish the content in the code.